# Missing email from "name" when using AWS SES API in C#

Tags: c#, email, amazon-web-services

When I send an email using AWS SES in a C# application the email names don't show in the received email - only the email addresses show.

The from/to emails I've added are strings in the form " Their Name". It's clearly understanding that as it's sending it to the right place, but just stripping out the names.

```
internal void SendEmail()
{
    try
    {
        // Construct an object to contain the recipient address.
        Destination destination = new Destination();
        destination.ToAddresses = toList;
        if (ccList.Count > 0) destination.CcAddresses = ccList;
        if (bccList.Count > 0) destination.BccAddresses = bccList;

        // Create the subject and body of the message.
        Body bodyobj = new Body();
        if(body!=null) bodyobj.Text = new Content(body);
        if(html!=null) bodyobj.Html = new Content(html);

        // Create a message with the specified subject and body.
        Message message = new Message(new Content(subject), bodyobj);

        // Assemble the email.
        SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest();
        request.Destination = destination;
        request.Message = message;
        request.Source = from;
        AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
        SendEmailResponse ser = client.SendEmail(request);
        sent=true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        errmsg = e.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide recipients with names in the standard email format

```
Fred Bloggs <fred.bloggs@exmaple.com>
```

If you specify your ToAddresses as a list of strings of that format, the name will be set properly.

This conforms to the [Internet Message Format (rfc5322)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt) spec. See section 3.4.

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks - I was putting the name after and AWS was ignoring it. Thanks

Comment: Great, glad that sorted it